# Rails + Postgres: How to select count of how many records are updated or inserted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

So I have an update statement:

```
UPDATE billing_infos set card_number = ''
FROM orders
WHERE billing_infos.order_id = orders.id ...);`
```

How would I find the count of how many records are updated by this statement?

I'm doing this in my console through `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute()` so it's just returning a `<PG::Result:0x007f9c99ef0370>` object.

Anyone know how I could do this using SQL or a Rails method?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
p = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(<query>)
p.cmd_status
```

This gives the command status. Something like

```
UPDATE 16
```

For more methods on PG::Result, refer [here](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/PG/Result)

Comment: I just noticed there is also cmd_tuples, which returns number of inserted/updated tuples (possibly just parsed cmd_status), so no parsing is necessary.

Answer (score 1):

While solution showed by Vimsha will definitely work, there is also another solution (assuming you use recent enough pg), which could be a bit nicer:

```
with u as (
    update ... returning 1
)
select count(*) from u;
```

That's one query, and it's technically a select, so you run it as any other select.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment of another answer, the easiest way is to use the   **`cmd_tuples`** attribute of the result

```
result = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("insert into tbl select 'test' col")
puts result.cmd_tuples
```

result

```
1
```